# Regex match inner '.'

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x

I would like to remove an inner sentence based on one word. So instead of just 'start' I would like the regex statement to return 'start.stop.'.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'start.stop.do nice.'
>>> re.sub(r'\..*nice.*', '', s)
'start'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [*negated character class*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) instead of `.*` to refuse of matching the dots in other sentences. And in order to preserving the last dot, you can use a [positive-lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for the last dot, to makes the regex engine doesn't capture that (just check its existence).

```
>>> re.sub(r'\.[^.]*nice[^.]*(?=\.)', '', s)
'start.stop'
```

Another good example by @bfontaine:

```
>>> s = "foo.bar.nice.qux"
>>> re.sub(r'\.[^.]*nice[^.]*(?=\.)', '', s)
'foo.bar.qux'
```

Comment: Note that if `s` is `"foo.bar.nice.qux"`, this will return `"foo.barqux"`.

Comment: @Kasramvd: You do not need the `(?=\.)` at all. Do you? See https://regex101.com/r/zN7xW9/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, if we want to replace the word only in a sentence (it should be ended with a period)

Comment: Ok, if *inner* sentence means only the sentence inside the sentences, then it is necessary.